# How to launch new terminal for each spawn command of Expect in perl

Tags: perl, terminal, expect

using Expect perl module, i have written script that uses ssh command on local host machine to emulate a terminal. so consider the below scenario, i have a perl script (say script.pl) which uses expect module, and have two commands of this type

```
$ssh = Expect->spawn("ssh -Y $loginname\@$systemname")
```

so the problem here is...i am using a terminal to execute script.pl and my code has two spawn commands. I noticed that two spawn commands are started within the terminal used to execute script.pl. But i want two new terminals for two spawn commands. So here there should be three terminals one for script.pl, two for each spawn commands in the script.pl.

Is there any way of achieving two new terminals from single perl script using Expect??

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there any way of achieving two new terminals from single perl script using Expect??"

Sure.  But a terminal is an application like anything.  You have to invoke it explicitly; all you are spawning is `ssh`.  Terminal applications are heterogeneous, so you need to figure out what terminal application is running on your system and how to get it to launch an application at start-up.  Eg, for the Xfce terminal something like:

```
$ssh = Expect->spawn("Terminal -e \"ssh -Y $loginname\@$systemname\"");
```

should work. Or perhaps better:

```
$ssh = Expect->spawn("Terminal", ("-e", "ssh -Y $loginname\@$systemname"));
```

However, your terminal is probably not the Xfce terminal. If you are on Windows, I believe it is `cmd`. On Linux it depends upon what is installed; if you are using a distro default it will be the terminal that came with the DE -- `gnome-terminal` for GNOME, `konsole` for KDE, etc.

It might make more sense, however, if you automate launching the terminals some other way and have them execute a script using expect/ssh at start-up.

Comment: Terminal is not going to forward the output/input from ssh to the pseudo tty handled by Expect, so this is mostly useless.

Comment: True, but that should be obvious -- I'm not familiar with Expect, does it require this?  Most terminals will return if invoked with a command when the command completes, I think.  But if the OP wants to *automate* a command so you can see it happening in a spawned terminal, probably that is not possible this way.  You might be able to launch a terminal -e "script that runs Expect", however ;)

Comment: Expect is used to automate tasks requiring user interaction, for instance as it is probably the case, passing the password to ssh. Otherwise it makes no sense to use Expect at all, one can just run `system('Terminal', '-e', $ssh_cmd)`